# KnockoutJS afterAdd animation outside of model?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Well im developing a knockout.js application and wonder where to put the animation functions if i do not want to keep them in the model(this does not seem like the correct place to have them)...

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is stopping you from referencing functions outside your model. Knockout looks to the viewmodel first, but will look to the global context if it doesn't find anything.

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { foreach: labels, afterAdd: app.animations.afterAdd}">
    <ol data-bind="text: $data"></ol>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
app = {};    
app.animations = {};    
app.animations.afterAdd = function(elem){
    $(elem).hide().slideDown('slow');
};
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/SpZJs/) demonstrating that this works.

Comment: This works great but is there some way to combine the 3 first javascript lines into one expression instead of 3??

Comment: @Petoj I only did it that way because I assume you will have other 'app-wide' code. If you don't need the first two lines, and you just want some global functions, you can do that. I would recommend this method though, because it will keep all your app code out of the global namespace.